# C literals, where are these stored

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const char * str) {
    str = "java";
}

void main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    const char *str = "erlang";
    f(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The output is "erlang" and I don't quite know why..
My current knowledge says that string literals "erlang" and "java" are both stored in the process adress space, within section "constants". And according to this, the fucntion f should change the pointer to point to "java", but this doesn't happen. Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because function arguments are *passed by value* in C and modifying arguments in callee won't affece caller's local variables.

Use pointers to modify caller's local variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const char ** str) { /* add * to declare pointer */
    *str = "java"; /* add * to access what is pointed */
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) { /* use standard signature */
    const char *str = "erlang";
    f(&str); /* add & to get a pointer pointing at str */
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C has *copy by value*. When `str` is passed as an argument to `f`, **it is copied first**, and that very copy is actually passed to `f`. Assigning `"java"` to that copy doesn't do anything to the original `str` in `main`.

Comment: Thanks, now I do understand. In my example I just change the pointer local to the function, and the original one still points to the "erlang" string.

Comment: @warchiefbinar Then please reward the creator of the answer and mark this problem as solved by clicking on the tick on the left of your favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the value that means call by value you will see the output as java if you pass the reference like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const char ** str) {
    *str = "java";
}

void main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    const char *str = "erlang";
    f(&str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

output:

```
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ gcc ptr1.c 
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 
java
```

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are its local variables. You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way (I changed the name of the parameter from `str` to `s` for clearity)

```
void f(/*const char * s*/) {
    const char *s = str;
    s = "java";
}
//...
const char *str = "erlang";
f(str);
```

Any changes of the local variable `s` does not influence on the original variable `str` used as the argument. The variable `str` itself was unchanged.

You should pass arguments by reference if you are going to change them in a function. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const char ** str ) 
{
    *str = "java";
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *str = "erlang";
    f( &str );
    printf( "%s\n", str );
}
```

The program output is

```
java
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main shall have return type int.

Comment: Thanks, the key is to  understand that function arguments within the function are treated as local variables. That explains a lot.

Comment: @warchiefbinar You are right. Parameters get copies of their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Many good answers all ready yet thought I'd try to perform a detailed walk-though with OP with slightly modified code.

Consider what happens with `f("Hello World")`.  `"Hello World"` is a *string literal*.  It initializes a `char` *array*.  When an *array* is passed to a function or assigned to a pointer, it is converted to the address of the first element of the array.  `f()` receives a copy of the address of `'H'` in its `str`.  #1 prints `"Hello World"`.  `str` is re-assigned to the address  of `'j'`.  #2 prints `"java"`.  The function ends *without affecting* `"Hello World"`.

With `str = "erlang"`, `str` receives the address of the `'e'`.  #3 prints `"erlang"`.  On the function call, the value of `main()`'s `str` is copied to the `f()`'s `str`.  #1 prints `"erlang"`. Like before,  `str` is re-assigned to the address  of `'j'`.  #2 prints `"java"`.  The function ends *without affecting* `main()`'s `str`.  #4 prints `"erlang"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const char * str) {
  printf("f()    before str='%s'\n", str); // #1
  str = "java";
  printf("f()    after  str='%s'\n", str); // #2
}

int main(void) {
  f("Hello World");
  puts("");

  const char *str = "erlang";
  printf("main() before str='%s'\n", str); // #3
  f(str);
  printf("main() after  str='%s'\n", str); // #4

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
f()    before str='Hello World'
f()    after  str='java'

main() before str='erlang'
f()    before str='erlang'
f()    after  str='java'
main() after  str='erlang'
```

---

As to OP's question:

> C literals, where are these stored?

The location of a string literal is not defined in C. It might use the  "process address space, within section *constants*", it might not.  What is important is that an array is formed and the address of the first character is given in assignment to a `const char *`.  Further detail: writing to this address is undefined behavior (UB), it may "work", fail, seg-fault, etc.

Comment: That's a really detailed explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would be more obvious if you changed the name of the argument for `f`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const char * foo) {
    foo = "java";
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    const char *str = "erlang";
    f(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

`foo` is a different variable to `str`. It has a different name, a different scope, and can contain a different value. The changes to `foo` won't propagate to `str`. If you wanted to modify `str` from within `f`, you would need to make `f` look like this:

```
void f(const char **foo) {
    *foo = "java";
}
```

... and pass a pointer to `str` to `f` like so: `f(&str);`.

---

Did you happen to notice how I changed `void main` to `int main`? There are only two signatures for `main` entry points (excluding the equivalents) that are guaranteed by the standard to be portable:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

... and ...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

Either way, `main` *always* returns `int` (or equivalent). This shouldn't inconvenience you too much, as in C99 (any half-decent compiler that's newer than fifteen years old) and C11 there's [this little gem](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1) which allows you to omit `return 0;` from `main`:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.

So if anything, your code using an `int main` entry point is not just portable but also one byte shorter than your code using a non-portable `void main` entry point.